# Best Regression with Binary Features

Tags: regression, modeling, linear-model, binary-data

I'm seeking to do a linear regression for an evaluation function in a board game.

My features are all (signed) binary 1 0 0 1 -1 1 0 0 0. Mostly zeros. Around 200 to an observation. I have 10 million observations with target values [-1000, 1000]. I'm wondering how this should affect my choice of regression model. I've tried with least squares and it gave very bad and unstable results.

Can you recommend me some good, linear, robust regression models, which perhaps take advantage of the simple format of my inputs?

Comment: Does "millions of those" refer to the number of observations, or the number of predictors? How many of each do you have? What is the purpose of the regression, do you want to predict? How did OLS yield bad & unstable results?

Comment: OLS gave very different values depending on what training dataset I generated. I assume due to outliers of large target values.

Comment: If you are still interested in this Q, you should give more details, maybe post some example data (or a link to the dataset), give some examples of output and show the problems. If you solved the problem yourself in the meantime, you could answer yourself!